# partial binomial

Tags: combinatorics

The following inequality of partial binomial expansions seems to be true:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} {n \choose i} q^{n - i} (1-q)^i \leq \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} {{n-r} \choose i} q^{n - r - i} (1-q)^i$

For $q \in [0,1]$ and integers $n, r$. $0 \leq r \leq n$. For example:

For $r=1$: $q^n \leq q^{n-1}$

For $r=2$: $q^n + n q^{n-1}(1-q) \leq q^{n-2} + (n-2) q^{n-3}(1-q)$

Is this true? Can you help me prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where does the inequality come from? It is true if $r=2$ and $n=3$, indeed
$$
q^3+3q^2(1-q) \le q+(1-q), 
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\forall q \in [0,1],\quad 2q^3-3q^2+1=(q-1)^2(2q+1) \ge 0.
$$

Comment: Hi Paolo. I actually want to prove that $\frac{1 - \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} {n \choose i} q^{n - i} (1-q)^i \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} {{n-r} \choose i} q^{n - r - i} (1-q)^i}{1 - \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} {n \choose i} q^{n - i} (1-q)^i}$ is bounded above by 2. If the inequality is true, it follows.

Comment: I think you want to add $0 \le r \le n$. When $r > n$ the left hand side evaluates to $1$ and the right hand side evaluates to $0$.

Comment: Peter Taylor, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to prove something stronger: $$\sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m + s}{i} q^{m + s - i} (1-q)^i \leq \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m}{i} q^{m - i} (1-q)^i$$ where $s \ge 0$ and $m \ge 0$.

Intuitively it's easy to see by thinking about pachinko. If we have an accumulator which starts at $0$ and a series of Bernoulli trials where we increment the accumulator (go right) with probability $q$ and leave it alone (go left) with probability $1-q$ then the LHS is the probability that the accumulator is less than $r$ after $m+s$ trials. But since the accumulator only increases, that probability must go down as $m+s$ goes up.

To formalise that,

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m}{i} q^{m - i} (1-q)^i = \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m}{i} q^{m - i} (1-q)^i (q + 1 - q) \\
= \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m}{i} q^{m + 1 - i} (1-q)^i + \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m}{i} q^{m - i} (1-q)^{i+1} \\
= \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m}{i} q^{m + 1 - i} (1-q)^i + \sum_{j = 1}^{r} \binom{m}{j-1} q^{m + 1 - j} (1-q)^{j} \\
= \binom{m}{0} q^{m + 1} + \sum_{i = 1}^{r-1} \binom{m+1}{i} q^{m + 1 - i} (1-q)^{i} + \binom{m}{r-1} q^{m + 1 - r} (1-q)^{r} \\
= \binom{m}{0} q^{m + 1} + \binom{m}{r-1} q^{m + 1 - r} (1-q)^{r} - \binom{m+1}{0} q^{m + 1} + \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m+1}{i} q^{m + 1 - i} (1-q)^{i} \\
= \binom{m}{r-1} q^{m + 1 - r} (1-q)^{r} + \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m+1}{i} q^{m + 1 - i} (1-q)^{i} \\
\geq \sum_{i = 0}^{r-1} \binom{m+1}{i} q^{m + 1 - i} (1-q)^{i}$$

And if $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: f(m+1) \le f(m)$ then by induction $\forall m,s \in \mathbb{N}: f(m+s) \le f(m)$.